# Sql query from multiple tables - joins not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried sub queries and join queries, but I cannot get  the right answer, as I need to retrieve data from different tables. This is what I am trying to do:

> Show the department Name, Street Address and
>   City of the department location and the Country Name
>   where the department is located for an employee
>   with the name Den Raphaely

I have tables like this.

COUNTRIES TABLE

- country_id
- country_name
- region_id

DEPARTMENT TABLE

- department_id
- department_name
- manager_id
- location_id

EMPLOYEES TABLE

- first_name
- last_name
- email
- phone
- salary
- commission
- department_id
- job_id
- hire_date

JOBS_HISTORY TABLE

- employee_id
- start_date
- end_date
- job_id
- department_id

JOB TABLE

- Job_id
- Min_salary
- Max_Salary

LOCATIONS TABLE

- Location_id
- Street_address
- Postal_code
- State
- Country_id

REGION TABLE

- region_id
- region_name

This is the attempted query

```
SELECT Employees.FIRST_NAME, Employees.LAST_NAME,
Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, Locations.Street_Address,
Locations.City, Countries.Country_Name FROM
Countries INNER JOIN Locations ON
Countries.Country_ID=Locations.Country_ID
INNER JOIN Departments ON
Locations.Location_id=Departments.LOCATION_ID
INNER JOIN Employees ON
Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID FROM Employees
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'Den' AND LAST_NAME LIKE 'Raphaely')
```

Comment: Please show us the query and table structure.

Comment: i am new here i dont how to upload pics but i am copying paste my sql server code

Comment: Please at least share the queries you have tried that failed. Reading your question and looking at your stuff this is a simple idea of using multiple inner joins to join table A to table B to table C so table A can access information from table C.  So what have you tried that failed?

Comment: @MageeWorld here is my wrong queries i am very new in sql i am sorry i know my question is so dumb
SELECT Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, Locations.Street_Address,
Locations.City, Countries.Country_Name FROM
Departments, Locations, Countries INNER JOIN
Employees ON (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM Employees
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'Den' AND LAST_NAME LIKE 'Raphaely'
= Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID AND INNER JOIN Locations 
ON Locations.Location_id = Departments.LOCATION_ID)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  here is my wrong queries i am very new in sql i am sorry i know my question is so dumb
SELECT Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, Locations.Street_Address,
Locations.City, Countries.Country_Name FROM
Departments, Locations, Countries INNER JOIN
Employees ON (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM Employees
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'Den' AND LAST_NAME LIKE 'Raphaely'
= Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID AND INNER JOIN Locations 
ON Locations.Location_id = Departments.LOCATION_ID)

Comment: @haider Well first off - your from statement isn't proper.  You need to select one table - inner join it to another table and then innerjoin it to a third table.  You can probably write your joins purely on id numbers as they exist in most of your other tables.  I'm not going to fully give you this answer because it seems like a homework question - but review your notes on inner joins and start over from scratch.

Comment: @MageeWorld This is not my home work i have reading week now so no study for now. my college provide us random stuff for practice (optional ) but unfortunately i lost my answer password i can get it back when college will open. I am doing it for my practice nothing else :)

Comment: @haider Try this as a starter. `Select Country.name, Region.name FROM Country INNER JOIN Region ON Country.region_id = Region.region_id`.  If you can understand how this works you can expand more inner joins to pull the exact data you want.  Focus on the ID columns in all your tables to link them

Comment: @MageeWorld
`SELECT Employees.FIRST_NAME, Employees.LAST_NAME,
Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, Locations.Street_Address,
Locations.City, Countries.Country_Name FROM
Countries INNER JOIN Locations ON
Countries.Country_ID=Locations.Country_ID
INNER JOIN Departments ON
Locations.Location_id=Departments.LOCATION_ID
INNER JOIN Employees ON
Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID FROM Employees
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE 'Den' AND LAST_NAME LIKE 'Raphaely')`
i think entire code is right in end i m doing wrong. In employee table department_ID id 3 times because its foreign key

Comment: @MageeWorld thats y i m getting result for other employee too but i need only for **Den Raphaely** but i cant retrieve it because in employee table department_ID is 3 times it is foreign key in employee table so it is showing for others employee too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name, l.street_address, l.city, c.country_name
FROM
employees e
INNER JOIN
department d
ON e.department_id = d.department_id
INNER JOIN
location l
ON d.location_id = l.location_id
INNER JOIN country c
ON c.country_id = l.country_id
WHERE
e.first_name = 'Den'
AND
e.last_name = 'Raphaely'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your JOINs with your filtering (WHERE) logic:

```
SELECT 
  Employees.FIRST_NAME, 
  Employees.LAST_NAME, 
  Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
  Locations.Street_Address, 
  Locations.City, 
  Countries.Country_Name 
FROM Countries 
   INNER JOIN Locations ON Countries.Country_ID=Locations.Country_ID
   INNER JOIN Departments ON Locations.Location_id=Departments.LOCATION_ID
   INNER JOIN Employees ON Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID = Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE Employees.FIRST_NAME LIKE 'Den' AND Employees.LAST_NAME LIKE 'Raphaely'
```